# What does [I mean in a scala ClassCastException error message?

Tags: scala

I'm getting the following error running a spark app:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [I
```

No, I didn't create a class named I or [I. It's kind of hard to google. Anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have something like this:

```
def retrieveArray(): Seq[Int] = Array(1)
retrieveArray().asInstanceOf[Array[Int]]
```

this is failing because when the `Array[Int]` is converted to a `Seq[Int]` it becomes `WrappedArray[Int]` that is a different type than `Array[Int]`

`retrieveArray().toArray` would make the conversion

Answer (score 2):

It means `Array[Int]`.

```
object Main extends App {
    println(classOf[Array[Int]])
}
```

Output:

```
class [I
```

See the Java documentation for [`Class.getName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--).